# How can I see in Lubuntu what RAM modules I have?

Tags: lubuntu, ram

I have the latest Lubuntu installed on a laptop.  How can I see how many RAM modules I have installed, and what type of RAM modules they are, without physically opening the laptop itself?  I can see how much RAM I have in total, using the System Profiler and Benchmark utility, but I want to know how many modules I have and what type of modules they are.

Thanks
Samuel

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 10):

One way to do this is installing `lshw` or `lshw-gtk`:

```
sudo apt-get install lshw-gtk
```

You can then run it (`sudo lshw-gtk`) and check your RAM entry:

[image]

As you can see in the image above, I have 2 RAM sticks installed, of 4GB each.

An other way is to use the command line version (showing partial output):

```
$ sudo lshw -class memory
*-memory
   description: System Memory
   physical id: 19
   slot: System board or motherboard
   size: 8GiB
 *-bank:0
      description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1067 MHz (0.9 ns)
      product: HMT351S6BFR8C-G7
      vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
      physical id: 0
      serial: 3B3BD95E
      slot: DIMM_A
      size: 4GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 1067MHz (0.9ns)
 *-bank:1
      description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1067 MHz (0.9 ns)
      product: HMT351S6BFR8C-G7
      vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
      physical id: 1
      serial: 3F114A3B
      slot: DIMM_B
      size: 4GiB
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 1067MHz (0.9ns)
```

Comment: Just in case someone is curious, after installing `lshw`, it can be found under Preferences > Hardware Lister

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dmidecode`:

```
sudo apt-get install dmidecode
```

To know how many RAM modules you have in your system, just type in a terminal:

```
sudo dmidecode -t 17
```

I get this kind of output for a system with 2 memory modules:

```
# dmidecode 2.12
# SMBIOS entry point at 0xbae9e000
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x0008, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0007
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelA-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 0
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1600 MHz
    Manufacturer: Hynix/Hyundai
    Serial Number: 316A2BC7
    Asset Tag: None
    Part Number: HMT41GS6MFR8C-PB  
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: 1600 MHz

Handle 0x0009, DMI type 17, 34 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0007
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: SODIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: ChannelB-DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK 2
    Type: DDR3
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 1600 MHz
    Manufacturer: Hynix/Hyundai
    Serial Number: 31CA2BB9
    Asset Tag: None
    Part Number: HMT41GS6MFR8C-PB  
    Rank: Unknown
    Configured Clock Speed: 1600 MHz
```